# autoconf unable to find pkg-config (PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG failing)

Tags: yocto, autotools, autoconf, bitbake

I am building a program in the yocto/openembedded cross-compile environment. It uses the following configure.ac file

```
AC_INIT([my-program], [1])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_PROG_CXX
AX_PTHREAD()
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG
if test -z "$PKG_CONFIG"; then
  AC_MSG_WARN([Cannot find pkg-config, make sure it is installed in your PATH])
fi
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBPNG, libpng >= 1.6.34)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(FREETYPE2, freetype2 >= 21.0.15)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(EGL, egl > 0)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLES2, glesv2 > 0)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLM, glm >= 0.9.9)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SPATIALITE, spatialite >= 4.3.0)
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The configure step fails because it cannot find the pkg-config config executeable. I know that pkg-config is correctly setup in the build environment because it works for other packages.

The log file shows that the PKG_CONFIG enivronment variable is not being set. This should be done by the `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG` command That would lead me to believe that something is wrong with my configure file or bitbake recipe.

**What am I missing in the configure file?**

For reference, here is the bitbake recipe file
https://gist.github.com/j-omega/15af56fce3dc7f515fedc7d891e0dd74

Comment: You need to replace `DEPENDS_${PN}` by `DEPENDS` in your recipe. Maybe try to remove PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG line or replace it by `AC_REQUIRE([PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKG_CONFIG is set correctly after I remove `AX_PTHREAD()`. This solves the problem and allows the configure step to complete successfully.